# Make OutputField Editable Per Condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field

I have outputfield to show the value of the field in **Edit** Visualforce page. I want to make this outputfield editable when checkbox field is checked

```
<apex:pageblocksection>    
      <apex:outputText value={!Object__c.ExampleField__c}>
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Now am adding one checkbox field and when this checkbox is checked, the outputtext field should become editable.

```
    <apex:pageblocksection>
          <apex:inputText value="{!Object__c.CheckboxField__c}"
    </apex:pageblocksection>

//Make the below field editable when above checkbox is checked

    <apex:pageblocksection>    
          <apex:outputText value="{!Object__c.ExampleField__c}">
    </apex:pageblocksection>
```

I have tried with having inputtext and rendered="{!IF(Object__c.CheckboxField__c == true, true, false)}". But it is not working as expected.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `apex:inputCheckbox` (instead of inputText) with action support, rerender the block containing input and output fields rendered conditionally.

Following is psuedo code:

```
<apex:pageblocksection>
    <apex:inputText value="{!Object__c.CheckboxField__c}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
            rerender="editableBlock" />
    </apex:inputText>
</apex:pageblocksection>

<!-- below field editable when above checkbox is checked -->
<apex:pageblocksection id="editableBlock">    
    <apex:outputText value="{!Object__c.ExampleField__c}" 
        rendered="{!NOT(Object__c.CheckboxField__c)}">
    <apex:inputText value="{!Object__c.ExampleField__c}" 
        rendered="{!Object__c.CheckboxField__c}">
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll mark this as answer. Once I did like this the formatting is collapsed. Can we do anything to bring back the default formatting?.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by formatting, unable to visualize!

Comment: I have pageblocksection inside another pageblocksection so the default style formatting of the Examplefield__c is collapsing. Is there any workaround for this to bring back the default stying?.

Comment: A pageblock section should never be inside another one, maybe render them conditionally